# Create a powershell dictionary

Tags: json, powershell, dictionary

I would like to copy a file's data that contains a dictionary structure into PowerShell. I've pasted the content and now I have a variable called `$dns`, this is its content:

```
{
    "ips":  {
                "10.20.30.40":  [
                                       {
                                           "rhost":  "DNS Name1.",
                                           "rdata":  [
                                                         "10.20.30.40"
                                                     ],
                                           "rrtype":  "A (1)",
                                           "ttl":  86400,
                                           "geo":  null,
                                           "source":  "DNSProvider1"
                                       }
                                   ],
                "40.50.60.70":  [
                                       {
                                           "rhost":  "DNS Name2.",
                                           "rdata":  [
                                                         "40.50.60.70"
                                                     ],
                                           "rrtype":  "A (1)",
                                           "ttl":  86400,
                                           "geo":  null,
                                           "source":  "DNSProvider1"
                                       }
                                   ]
            }
}
```

I want to run some manipulations on it, should I convert it to an Object or something else?

Just to clarify myself, when I use this kind of object in Python, I can use this object like this:

```
dns['ips']
```

The result looks like this:

```
{
'10.20.30.40': 
    [
        {
            'geo': null,
            'rdata': ['10.20.30.40'],
            'rhost': 'DNS Name1.',
            'rrtype': 'A (1)',
            'source': 'DNSProvider1',
            'ttl': 86400
        }
    ],
'40.50.60.70': 
    [
        {
            'geo': null,
            'rdata': ['40.50.60.70'],
            'rhost': 'DNS Name2.',
            'rrtype': 'A (1)',
            'source': 'DNSProvider1',
            'ttl': 86400
        }
    ]
}
```

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the `ConvertFrom-Json` cmdlet:

```
($dns | ConvertFrom-Json).ips
```

Comment: Thanks Martin, but it looks like the powershell doesn't recognize the ":" . 
The error I'm getting is:
    ConvertFrom-Json : Invalid object passed in, ':' or '}' expected. (1): {
    At line:1 char:9
    + ($dns | ConvertFrom-Json).ips
    +         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [ConvertFrom-Json], ArgumentEx
       ception
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Co
       mmands.ConvertFromJsonCommand

Comment: This is working fine here with your json. How do you retrieve `$dns`?

Comment: I did the same. Please try to copy paste your json from stackoverflow into a new file and try it again.

Answer (score 1):

You might need the `-raw` switch...

```
$dns = gc C:\tmp\dns.json -Raw
($dns | ConvertFrom-Json).ips
```